# How to have both SSD and HDD on a laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, thinkpad

I recently bought a Lenovo ThinkPad E540

I want to boost its speed up, so I decided to buy an SSD, but I don't know if it replaces the current HDD or it can be installed beside it, I prefer to keep the HDD

[This article](https://devsector.wordpress.com/2014/08/30/lenovo-thinkpad-edge-e540-ssd-installation/) shows that it can be installed beside it, that's good, but I suspect that the SSD in this page is a special SSD

In general, how one can have both HDD (for capacity) and SSD (for speed) on a laptop?

Comment: As mentioned in the article, you'll have to get an M.2 SSD if you want to keep the internal HDD. It's much smaller than 2.5" SATA SSD's. I think you should read the article again -- it's very detailed and pretty well-written and contains every bit of information you need, including installation.

Comment: @geewee my Enlgish is not that good, besides while searching SSD never I seen that type of SSD or its usage, then how can I keep my HDD and SDD both

Comment: Why down vote, yes it is in the article, but the question has an important point, I didn't know that SSD is replacing HDD,

Comment: I issued a downvote because the question isn't clear.

Comment: @Ahmad: I didn't down vote your question. My English isn't impeccable either, so I couldn't care less about your mastery of the language. Peace.

Comment: @Ramhound you may consider it now, is it unclear? It was my first question here and because of the down-votes I can't ask any more questions, while i think it is not fair to the question.

Comment: @Ahmad - People don't get question banned because of a single question with 3 downvotes.  You have asked other questions in the past that have not been well accepted, they might have been deleted by you or the community, but a single bad question wouldn't bare you from asking additional questions.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you, now that you read the question, please reconsider your vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the laptop that you have, the only option you would have would be to replace a detachable CD-rom with a hard drive bay. You would probably have to remove your internal hard drive, install the SSD (make it bootable/clone your existing system HD onto it), and move the 1T HD to the external bay.

Something similar to this 
http://www.cdw.com/shop/products/Lenovo-storage-bay-adapter/3212343.aspx

You may also want to look at the lenovo forums where someone is asking the same question about the E540
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/11e-Windows-E-and-Edge-series/2nd-hard-disk-to-E540/td-p/1352901

Answer (score 2):

From that article, it states that it can be:

> coupled with an optional 16 GB SSD cache module.

This is usually a M.2 form factor (mSATA) SSD, but it can't be used for anything other than caching frequently accessed files. To install that ADATA SSD, you would need to *replace* your current OS/boot drive.

**UPDATE:** If you wanted to have both, then if the laptop has a SATA DVD drive (most modern laptops do) you could take the laptop apart, release the DVD drive, and install a standard 2.5" SSD

Comment: `This is usually a M.2 form factor (mSATA) SSD, but it can't be used for anything other than caching frequently accessed files.`. The small separate SSD caches often can be used as a normal drive (as mentioned in the article) but it sometimes requires a lot of configuration settings to be changed and obviously the size is very limited.

Comment: @James Indeed it does, but for simplicity, I omitted that fact.

Comment: That's odd! I need both HDD (1 T) and SDD, then you mean there is no way to have both of them?

Comment: @Ahmad Not unless the SSD has the M.2 Form Factor, and even then, you'd need to reinstall to be *able* to use the SSD

Comment: You may also want to answer that general question I asked, I wonder how this question should get down voted, its normal that one want both SSD and HDD on a laptop. (I even think one of them could replace DVD drive), or maybe an external SSD is the solution!

Comment: @James The 128G for the OS is good, then you mean its not just for cashing and can be used as a drive for OS and save some files?

Comment: @Ahmad: Your laptop may have a 16GB SSD in there already for storing frequently accessed files and/or speeding up the boot times, this is something that laptop makers often do (typically with software called ExpressCache) but not all versions of the E540 have it.

Comment: @James I opened it up, nothing was there, In general, if I can find such a SSD, (Which I am not sure can be found easily here in Iran) then the speed I expect from my laptop would be met? I would like when I open many files (pdf,...) the computer be fast.

Comment: @Ahmad: You would need to be careful that you get the right type of M.2 card (42mm) as there are different sizes that won't physically fit. If you don't need your DVD drive then you may be better off with the bay adapter.

Comment: @James Thank you for the hint, but I repeat my last question, do you recommend to get that cache (for example 64gig) or to get an SSD in replace of Hard?